# Test if div is active jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div and i want if it is `active` do something if is not cancel the changement..

This is Html :

```
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Css:

```
.heart:active {
  background-position: -2800px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
}
.heart.active{
  background-position: -2800px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
}
```

What i tried to do :

```
jQuery('.heart').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
   if( $('.heart').css('active') != null )  { 
    /* Change*/ 
} 
else { 
    /*Cancel change*/
}
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()`

```
jQuery('.heart').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function instead of css as you are adding a class not a css property

```
$('.heart').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   if( $('.heart').hasClass('active') )  { 
    /* Change*/ 
} 
else { 
    /*Cancel change*/
}
});
```